# Modal Dialog is not working in Chrome

Tags: javascript, google-chrome

In the below code i have a modal popup which is not working in google chrome now.last 3 months it is working fine in chrome .Now i face this issue.

```
function ShowPopUp() {            
       var myWindow = window.showModalDialog("/Transaction/QuoteFromVendor.aspx", "QuoteFromVendor", "width=900,height=200");

       }
```

Comment: Explain what isn't working?

Comment: "In May 2015 this setting will be removed and showModalDialog will be completely removed from Chromium." - We're not there yet, but you may want to consider replacing it while you've got time. Source: http://blog.chromium.org/2014/07/disabling-showmodaldialog.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

showModalDialog has been deprecated from web standards and shouldn't be used. The following explanation can be found on [Mozilla.org's web API docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window.showModalDialog) - I would guess that Chrome finally removed this.

> Deprecated This feature has been removed from the Web standards.
>   Though some browsers may still support it, it is in the process of
>   being dropped. Do not use it in old or new projects. Pages or Web apps
>   using it may break at any time.

I'd suggest replacing it with something like [jQuery UI's dialog](http://jqueryui.com/dialog/)

Comment: Use quote markup, not code, for quotes from standards.